# Stored Procedures Python

Tags: python, sql-server, amazon-web-services, stored-procedures

I need to create a linked server in MS SQL Server for 2 AWS RDS servers, 
from Python 2.7. For this I use the **pymssql library**. The SQL commands are executed with a SQL Client without problems, the linked servers are created, they can be consulted that exist and can be used.

The problem occurs when you execute a SQL creation in Python (from an instance AWS Linux, in the same AZ), then you get the following error message.

```
Simple SQL queries from python (such as a Select) work without problems using pymssql.
```

The same happens when a stored procedure is created in the database and it called from python, if the instructions to create the linked servers are included then the same error is received. If you create the procedure in the sql in python the result is similar.

Does anyone know how to do it? Thank you very much for the help.

**Linkedserver Commands:**

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'linkserver1', @srvproduct=N'', @provider=N'SQLNCLI', @datasrc=N'aa.bb.cc.dd';

EXEC master.dbo.sp_dropserver @server = N'linkserver1';

EXEC sys.sp_linkedservers;
```

**Python Code:**

```
**import pymssql
def main():
    conn = pymssql.connect(server, user, clave, base)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'RDSPrivate01', @srvproduct=N'', @provider=N'SQLNCLI', @datasrc=N'win-01.nnnnnn.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com'")
if __name__== "__main__":
  main()**
```

**Message Error:**

> cursor.execute("EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server =
>   N'RDSPrivate01', @srvproduct=N'', @provider=N'SQLNCLI',
>   @datasrc=N'win-01.nnnnnnnnnnn.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com'")   File
>   "src/pymssql.pyx", line 468, in pymssql.Cursor.execute
>   pymssql.OperationalError: (15002, "The procedure
>   'sys.sp_addlinkedserver' cannot be executed within a transaction.
>   DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server error:
>   Check messages from the SQL Server\n")

**Links used:**
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/implement-linked-servers-with-amazon-rds-for-microsoft-sql-server/

http://www.pymssql.org/en/stable/pymssql_examples.html#important-note-about-cursors

Comment: Try `execute_non_query()` instead of `execute()`

Comment: Tomalak:   1.- you need to change cursor. to conn. (the cursor object does not have the function execute_non_query)   2.- you must import _mssql.  3.- Should EXEC be used?. Finally, I obtain : "Could not find stored procedure 'master.dbo.sp_addlinkserver".   Thanks for your suggestion, but it's not.

Comment: I dug through the source code of the module for a function that talks to the database *without creating a transaction*. Maybe it wasn't the right module I looked at, but that's besides the point. You can use the same approach, it's all open source after all. (Unless the documentation also contains this info, which you definitely should check as well.)